# PowerShell - Display all properties, including hidden ones

Tags: powershell

Q1. Why does `-Properties *` not list all properties?

Q2. How can I list all *hidden* properties of an object, including constructed attributes?

**Example 1: Counts**

```
$u = "myUsername"
(Get-ADUser $u -Properties *                                     | Get-Member | Measure-Object).Count
(Get-ADUser $u -Properties *,msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Get-Member | Measure-Object).Count

#Output:
#211
#212
```

**Example 2: Missing Property**

```
Get-ADUser $u -Properties * | Select msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
Get-ADUser $u -Properties *,msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed  | Select msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed

#Output:
#msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
#-----------------------------------
#                                   
#133330391314691704
```

Comment: Using `*` will make `Get-ADUser` return all properties _that are set_ - it doesn't include unset/empty attribute values unless explicitly requested

Comment: Most likely you would need to query the schema to get all possible `user` object class attributes and then use that list on `-Properties`

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/1739099/447008

Comment: @lit, that's the same SU post Santiago previously linked to, and it actually points back to the SO post that this question was now closed as a duplicate of. The sample code in _this_ question suggests that the claim in the linked SU post that specifying _one_ constructed attribute retrieves them _all_ isn't actually true (I've left a comment to that effect there).

Comment: I'll be fixing that once I confirm to be the same, I left Mr. mklemento a comment back. Always a pleasuring regardless of the feedback reason to hear from the PS greats!! Woo!!